# Can't update frames

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

My Xcode project has done some very strange things today. First, it kept giving me a SIGABRT error on one of my pages for my tab bar view controller. I erased all connections, and the error went away and I was able to view the page in the simulator. I made one connection from the storyboard my swift file, and the error came up again.

I decided to just start from scratch with another view controller (it wasn't too extensive at the time). I was trying to add new constraints and then update frames (to see exactly how it will layout), but it won't let me update frames no matter what constraints I lay out. Also, even if I just layout one constraint, the constraints also turn blue, indicating there is no ambiguity, which is definitely not the case.

Does anyone know what this could be?